# Why Creating new VM in Microsoft Azure, force creating a new storage account

Tags: virtual-machine, azure

I have an Azure storage account located @ North Europe

Now I am creating a new VM. 
Going through the settings until the VM step $3: storage settings.
The Storage Account does not allow to select the existing storage account

> No storage accounts found in the selected subscription and location
>   'North Europe'

thus a new storage account must be created.

Why the VM can not reside on the existing storage account?
Should I really care?

Another question is what does this setting mean. At the first step of the VM setting, there is another Location setting. whats the difference?

Answer (score 0):

About the first step location of VM setting and the step $3: storage settings, actually both are the region of datacenter where you VM and disks located. We should choose the same location in a resource group.

**“The Storage Account does not allow to select the existing storage account”** 
Here are two choices for you.

1. If you have VM disk type HDD, you should choose the **standard** performance of storage account;
2. If you have VM disk type SSD, you should choose the **premium** performance of storage account.

That is to say, the VM disk type should match the storage account performance. If you existed storage account does not match when you create the VM, you can create a new account. But before these, we must confirm that the storage account location is the same as the VM location.